# Limit of a sequence (definition)

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition, epsilon-delta

Let $$ (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$ be a sequence.

According to the definition of limit, it is said that
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=L \Leftrightarrow  \left(\forall \varepsilon>0, \ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \ n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow \left|a_n-L \right|<\varepsilon \right).
 $$

About the details, does it really matter, whether you say $$ n \ge n_0 \ \mathrm{or} \ n > n_0 ?$$

And why would $$ n_0 $$ have to be an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need that $n_0$ is an integer and it doesn't matter whether we use $\ge$ or $>$ both lead to an equivalent definition.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question, no it does not particularly matter as both statements will hold true for some epsilon greater than 0.

$n_o$ refers to the $n_o$ term of the sequence and thus is an integer. The limit $L$ however can be a real number.

Comment: Not necessarly $n_0$ needs to be an integer, the definition works fine alfo with $n_0 \in \mathbb R$. But of course we can also use $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ as in te given example.